# Dropdownlist Postback interferes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

My ASP page has a DropDownList (DDL) and a bunch of checkboxes. When my user selects a DDL item, I have some JS/jQuery code to make several checkboxes invisible according to some logic. However, the postback of the DDL, needed to run the C# code-behind event handler, causes a redraw of the entire page and makes all checkboxes visible.

How can I prevent the postback from wiping out the actions of the JS? Should I store visibility bits in something like ViewState?

Is it possible to have the JS code run AFTER the postback, instead of before?

Is it possible/easy to use CallBack instead of PostBack for the ASP DropDownList? I was thinking that the fun of Ajax was avoiding postbacks and only updating the control instead of the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the dropdown posts back in the same action that you flip the switch for the checkboxes, why not then put the logic to show/hide checkboxes on the server instead of the client?  You can use the hidden field approach, and that would work fine.

The callback means the UI needs updated by JavaScript.  I don't know what all the postback updates, but you would have to send everything up via JSON, and refresh the UI via JavaScript.  So only you can make that call.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Apparently, using ASP, you cannot just mix with any amount of JS. And with ASP, there are many options to achieve the desired effects.